# Iterating through select items on AJAX page with Scrapy and Splash

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am scraping a page, using both Scrapy and Splash. The page contains a dropdown box (technically, a select HTML element). Each time an element is selected in the dropdown box, a new page is loaded using AJAX.

The HTML segment below, is a simplified version of the page I'm processing:

```
<html>
    <head><title>Title goes here ...</title></head>
    <body>
        <select class="foo">
            <option value=100 data-reactid=1>One</option>
            <option value=200 data-reactid=2>Two</option>
            <!-- ... -->
            <option value=900 data-reactid=9>Nine</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Snippet of my scrapy/splash code:

```
# Fetch the options ... now what ?
options = response.css("select[class=foo] option[data-reactid]")
```

How do I programatically use Splash to 'click' and receive the reloaded AJAX page in my response object?

Comment: Do these ajax requests have the same format? Rather to simulate click action, maybe you can just programtically construct that format and send ajax request to get response.

Comment: @Sraw AJAX means that javascript is being run in the browser when the element is clicked.

Comment: Surely I know, but they are also no more than normal http requests. If you use chrome, you can see these requests under "Network" in developer tool. So you can also simulate a ajax request just like you `GET` or `POST` to a website.

Comment: I mean, if these ajax requests have the same format, and you can easily construct this format. It is also easy for you to directly simulate these ajax requests even without crawling this html page.

Comment: @Sraw refer to my previous comment.

Comment: If you can give a real web page as example, I will give an example for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try to use Splash's `execute` endpoint with LUA script that will fill the `select` with each `option`'s value and return the result. Something like:

```
...
script = """
function main(splash)
    splash.resource_timeout = 10
    splash:go(splash.args.url)
    splash:wait(1)
    splash:runjs('document.getElementsByClassName("foo")[0].value = "' .. splash.args.value .. '"')
    splash:wait(1)
    return {
        html = splash:html(),
    }
end
"""

# base_url refers to page with the select
values = response.xpath('//select[@class="foo"]/option/@value').extract()
for value in values:
    yield scrapy_splash.SplashRequest(
        base_url, self.parse_result, endpoint='execute',
        args={'lua_source': script, 'value': value, 'timeout': 3600})
```

Of course, this isn't tested, but you might start there and play with it.

Comment: Thanks very much for this - I just noticed your answer. I have upvoted it, because it gives me something to get started with. I will accept the answer once I am able to work to a solution from the starting point you provided in your answer - I may come back to you with a question if I get stuck in working out a solution - hope you don't mind.

Comment: Sure, ask when you need.

Comment: Could you explain this line?: `splash:runjs('document.getElementsByClassName("foo")[0].value = "' .. splash.args.value .. '"')`  I don't understand how this relates top the "clicking" of the dropdown element on the page.

Comment: The corresponding line sets value for the select control. That might trigger AJAX code linked to this event (i.e. changing option selected).

Comment: Thanks. I'm still working on this. Hope to get this sorted out soon.